# XCode builds taking forever (but succeeding) when touching a specific CoreData entity

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, core-data, cloudkit

I have an app that uses CoreData/iCloud NSPersistentCloudContainer. I recently added a Reminder Entity, and I'm finding that touching this entity is making my XCode build times super slow, although they do succeed and the app does not run slow on the simulator once it builds. The build times are so slow, that if my code has any type of error (i.e. missing a bracket), I get an error message with no helpful description ("The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions")

I've narrowed down specific lines that I can comment out, and have the app build at a reasonable speed. It appears to be anytime I'm touching this Reminder entity. Was wondering if I was doing something wrong with how I'm accessing Reminders? I haven't had this issue with any other entity in my model.

```
ForEach(dataModel.activeReminders){ reminder in
  if(reminder.note != nil && reminder.time! < Date()){ //If I comment these lines out, the app builds normally
    VStack{
        NoteView(namespace: namespace, note: reminder.note!)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        NoteViewFooter(namespace: namespace, note: reminder.note!)

        HStack{

            Button{
                withAnimation(.easeIn){
                    reminder.isCompleted = true //If I comment these lines out, the app builds normally
                }
                dataModel.saveMoc()
                dataModel.getReminders()
            }label:{
                HStack{
                    Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)

                    Text("Mark as Complete")
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                .font(.footnote)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .padding(.vertical, 6)
                .background(Color("ReminderGreen"))
                .cornerRadius(20)
            }

            Button{

                model.selectedNote = reminder.note

                withAnimation(.easeIn){
                    showEditAlert = true
                }
            }label:{
                Text("Edit alert")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                    .font(.footnote)
                    .padding(.vertical, 6)
                    .foregroundColor(Color("AccentColor"))
                    .background(Color("SelectedColor"))
                    .cornerRadius(20)
            }

        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .padding(.horizontal, 24)
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    .padding(.bottom, 16)
} //If I comment these lines out, the app builds normally
```

Here are some screenshots of my CoreData model, the calls I run to load the data, and a screenshot of the code listed above.

[image: CoreData Model]

[image: CoreData Call]

[image: Image of the screen]

Comment: Did you check the build log in Xcode to see what takes so long time?

Comment: Try to add an « else » that display an EmptyView() . With SwiftUI, if a ForEach if there is the possibility that nothing is displayed, that gives the kind of message about reasonable time.

Comment: I tried adding the else with an EmptyView() and looking at the build log, and I'm still seeing that compiling this view that has the code above is taking 30s compared to every other process taking less than 1s. This is what I expected, since i believe the lines of code I commented out above are what is taking so long. I just can't seem to figure out why?

Comment: From what I saw  with SwiftUI, you must always be sure that each item of a ForEach generates a view. You must also be sure that if there is nothing to loop for you generate a view (EmptyView for example). This kind of problem will generate the long compilation.

Comment: Yea I added an if(dataModel.activeReminders.isEmpty != false) around the forEach, and having my else statement load an EmptyView instead of running the forEach, but the compile time is still long if I uncomment the lines touching the reminder entity.